# RS485 hardware RTS on SC16IS752 not working when it is enabled in device tree overlay

Tags: drivers, device-tree

I'm trying to make SC16IS752 (SPI to UART converter) work in RS485 mode by using device tree overlay (without running C application at boot).

I took original overlay source for SC16IS752 from official sources at github:

[sc16is752-spi1-overlay.dts](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.4.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/sc16is752-spi1-overlay.dts)

Without adding `linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time;` line it works like this:
(RTS is always HIGH)

[image: no device tree flag]

I changed `fragment@1` part like this and added RS485
(I also changed clock freq because I'm using 1.843200MHz crystal in my hardware, not 14.xxxxMHz):

```
fragment@1 {
    target = <&spi1>;
    frag1: __overlay__ {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&spi1_pins &spi1_cs_pins>;
        cs-gpios = <&gpio 18 1>;
        status = "okay";

        /* RS485 SUPPORT */
        linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time;
        rs485-rts-delay = <0 0>;
        /* RS485 SUPPORT END */

        sc16is752: sc16is752@0 {
            compatible = "nxp,sc16is752";
            reg = <0>; /* CE0 */
            clocks = <&sc16is752_clk>;
            interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
            interrupts = <24 2>; /* IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING */
            gpio-controller;
            gpio-cells = <2>;
            spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;

            /* I also tried to put it here */
            /* but RTS is always HIGH */
            /* RS485 SUPPORT */
            /* linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time; */
            /* rs485-rts-delay = <0 0>; */
            /* RS485 SUPPORT END */

            sc16is752_clk: sc16is752_clk {
                compatible = "fixed-clock";
                #clock-cells = <0>;
                clock-frequency = <1843200>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I compiled `dts` file, I put it to `/boot/overlays` and I have added proper line in `/boot/config.txt` to use that overlay.

RTS line now is always LOW (without flag it was HIGH - see image above):

[image: device tree flag set]

So this flag has been read by kernel/driver, but it RTS does nothing when I'm sending data. It should work like this:

[image]

Last screenshot with working RS485 mode was taken after I turned RS485 mode in C program like this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/serial.h>

/* Include definition for RS485 ioctls: TIOCGRS485 and TIOCSRS485 */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main(int argc, char *artv[]){

        /* Open your specific device (e.g., /dev/mydevice): */
        int fd = open ("/dev/ttySC0", O_RDWR);
        if (fd < 0) {
                /* Error handling. See errno. */
                return -1;
        }

        struct serial_rs485 rs485conf;

        /* Enable RS485 mode: */
        rs485conf.flags |= SER_RS485_ENABLED;

        /* Set logical level for RTS pin equal to 1 when sending: */
        rs485conf.flags |= SER_RS485_RTS_ON_SEND;
        /* Set logical level for RTS pin equal to 0 after sending: */
        rs485conf.flags &= ~(SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND);

        rs485conf.delay_rts_before_send = 0;
        rs485conf.delay_rts_after_send = 0; // zero! nie obsługiwane przez SC16IS752

        if (ioctl (fd, TIOCSRS485, &rs485conf) < 0) {
                /* Error handling. See errno. */
                return -2;
        }

        /* Use read() and write() syscalls here... */

        /* Close the device when finished: */
        if (close (fd) < 0) {
                /* Error handling. See errno. */
                return -3;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

So, the question is **how to do it without C program**?

**Why setting rs485 mode in device tree is not enough?**

I'm suspecting that the driver has no default configuration, and it has zeroes in both SER_RS485_RTS_ON_SEND and SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND flags. If this is true - (extra question) should I report issue with this driver in this situation?

Useful resources:

- SC16IS7xx driver I'm using: [github link](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/serial/sc16is7xx.c)
- Device tree binding documentation for RS485: [github link](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.4.y/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/serial/rs485.txt)
- Original overlay without RS485: [github link](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.4.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/sc16is752-spi1-overlay.dts)

---

Edit/added later:

I also noticed, that when my overlay was applied at boot and I run this code (it is supposed to read flags from port, I'm not sure if it is correct).

```
    /* Reading rs485conf struct from port */
    if (ioctl (fd, TIOCGRS485, &rs485conf) < 0) {
            /* Error handling. See errno. */
            return -2;
    }

    printf("Before: ");
    binprintf(rs485conf.flags); // function that prints int as binary
    printf("\n");
```

all flags are empty. So... overlay changed RTS state after boot, but flags on port are zeroes? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this question, like I did while trying to get a SC16IS752 working on I2C on a RPi, the answer is, in brief:

- The `sc16is7xx.c` driver doesn't have any code calling `uart_get_rs485_mode()` as described in [`serial_core.c`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/1c64f4bc22811d2d371b271daa3fb27895a8abdd/drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c#L3092) and which appears in several other serial drivers;
- the device tree property `rs485-rts-active-low` appears only to have been added to RPi 5.3 and later kernels (see this [commit](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/f1e5b618c1c26cb8b5818e36f996e8c2fbedbeb7)).

To address the first issue, I have made a couple of small changes to the `sc16is7xx.c` driver, see this [commit](https://github.com/dkirkham/linux/commit/8cda6263f7d5ff0cb18dd15bda49d007c93cd3a1). The `uart_get_rs485_mode()` function picks up the relevant properties from the device tree and writes a `struct serial_rs485`, the same as used for the `TIOCSRS485` ioctl. The changes haven't been regression tested, but it is currently working reliably for me on my breadboarded SC16IS752 interface.

This commit is based on the 5.4 kernel, so supports the `rs485-rts-active-low` property and therefore works nicely with my MAX3072 line drivers.

Here is a part of my overlay file:

```
fragment@1 {
    target = <&i2c_arm>;
    __overlay__ {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        status = "okay";

        sc16is752: sc16is752@48 {
            compatible = "nxp,sc16is752";
            reg = <0x48>; /* i2c address */
            clocks = <&sc16is752_clk>;
            interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
            interrupts = <18 2>; /* IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING */
            gpio-controller;
            #gpio-cells = <2>;
            i2c-max-frequency = <400000>;
            linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time;
            rs485-rts-active-low;
        };
    };
};
```

And here is a scope image showing it working:

[image: I2C and RS485 signalling]

For reference: `D8=SCL`, `D9=SDA`, `D10=_IRQ`, `D11=TXD`, `D12=_RTS`, `D13=RXD`, `Analog1=one RS485 line`, `Analog2=RXD` (same as D13). The command response is coming from a remote ModBus device. Note that `_RTS` is high (3.3V) during transmit, as there is a double negation.